# golang can not find package gin in sub directory

Tags: go, go-gin

I get the following error message:

```
controllers/user.go:4:2: cannot find package "(underscore)/home/ubuntu/goapi/src/github.com/roes/api/vendor/github.com/gin-gonic/gin" 
in any of: /usr/local/go/src/(underscore)/home/ubuntu/goapi/src/github.com/roes/api/vendor/github.com/gin-gonic/gin (from $GOROOT) 
     /home/ubuntu/goapi/src/_(underscore)/home/ubuntu/goapi/src/github.com/roes/api/vendor/github.com/gin-gonic/gin (from $GOPATH)
```

go env

```
GOPATH="/home/ubuntu/goapi"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
```

folder structure

```
github.com/rose
 api
  main.go // the loading gin is ok here
  controller
   |-user.go //with import ( "github.com/gin-gonic/gin" ) : error
```

go env looks Ok.

Some more code:

```
  package controller

  import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
    //      "github.com/astaxie/beego/orm"
    "../database"
    "../models"
  )

  func init() {
    database.ConnectToDb()
    ORM = database.GetOrmObject()
  }

   //UserController ...
   type UserController struct{}

   func createUser(c *gin.Context) {
```

example resource: https://github.com/thearavind/go-gin-pg, nothing wrong with this example. I just make it like MVC structure

---

I did remove go.
and install it again flow Linux version
https://golang.org/doc/install
then

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

then
https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#use-a-vendor-tool-like-govendor
the example code run ok.
when I add controller folder with user.go with

```
 import( "github.com/gin-gonic/gin")
```

full code

```
  package controller
  import( "github.com/gin-gonic/gin")
  func somestring(){
    return "hello world"
  }
```

in the main.go i use above

```
   curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gin-gonic/gin/master/examples/basic/main.go > main.go
```

add to import

```
    "./controller"
    "fmt"
```

add to the main function

```
        user := new(controller.somestring)
        fmt.Printf(user)
```

I understand this is not a good code for me, but will produce this error again, like so:

```
 controller/user.go:4:2: cannot find package "github.com/gin-gonic/gin" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin (from $GOROOT)
/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin (from $GOPATH)
```

(no underscore this time)

No luck, reinstall go

---

I am able to find the path, but not the underscore thing

```
 08:56:35 ~/go/src/github.com/jerry/core$ cd /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/jerry/core/vendor/github.com/gin-gonic/
 08:56:45 ~/go/src/github.com/jerry/core/vendor/github.com/gin-gonic$
```

Comment: The import path is "github.com/gin-gonic/gin", not "/home/ubuntu/goapi/src/github.com/roes/api/vendor/github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

Comment: yes, I don't understand this part. as I understand, it should call the Globally installed package, and I do have "/home/ubuntu/goapi/src/github.com/roes/api/vendor/github.com/gin-gonic/gin" except the (underscore at the front)

Comment: In your folder structure you have `github.com/rose`. In your error messages you have  `github.com/roes`. Why?

Comment: I don't know. I believe it look for all packages but not gin. the funny thing is I can load gin package in main.go tho.

Comment: That error message is only possible if your code says `import "_/home/ubuntu/goapi/src/github.com/roes/api/vendor/github.com/gin-gonic/gin"`, which is wrong. Go wouldn't look in `$GOPATH/src/_home/ubuntu/...` otherwise.

Comment: does anyone know why there is an underscore? please. I can find the gin in the right path, same as above just not the underscore

Answer (score 1):

If go mod is not enabled in root path of project then you have to enable go mod and install the package.

For example , a package named "/gin-gonic/gin" is missing or you cannot find this.

Please run this in src folder or parallel to github.com folder.

```
$ GO111MODULE=on go get -u github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.3.0
```

1. I am assuming your **$GOPATH is Users/YourUserName/go**

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

since Go v1.11, you can use go modules which let you create project with modules outside of the Go src/ folder. To do so, you can simply run the command `go build` at your root folder.

This article explains it all: https://medium.com/mindorks/create-projects-independent-of-gopath-using-go-modules-802260cdfb51

Gl & Hf :D

Answer (score -1):

maybe I just miss out this step for every folder in the project folder. 
(very important)

```
  mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/myusername/project && cd "$_"
```

I keep asking my friend Google, the answer is:  goVendor depend on the $GOPHATH a lot. 
then I Create the controller folder with above command. so every folder too. no problem :)

**Thank you to everyone Helping and Viewing**

Comment: yeah, not about the go vendor path thing, the problem still exist